# ¿Como ordeno los índices (index) de un pivot table?

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

Tengo el siguiente `DataFrame` que selecciono como índices el  'Mes' y 'Dia' para realizar un `pivot table`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
subset7=subset7.pivot_table(subset7,index=['Mes','Dia'],columns=['FormaPago'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Con lo anterior obtengo el dataframe con los meses y dias desordenados. He buscado por todos lados y no encontré alguna solución.

Si hago lo siguiente, me ordena los meses mas no los días:

```
order=[]
for i in range(1,13):
    order.append(i)
for i in range(len(order)):
    order[i] = str(order[i])
order

['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']

subset7=subset7.pivot_table(subset7,index=['Mes','Dia'],columns=['FormaPago'],aggfunc=np.sum).loc[order]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe con

```
subset7['Mes'].astype(np.int32)
subset7['Dia'].astype(np.int32)
subset7.sort_values(by=["Mes","Dia"],inplace=True)
```

como me aconsejaron no dio resultado marca error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En primer lugar el DF que muestras al principio está agrupado según el mes, tampoco muestras los datos en formato de texto.

Comment: En segundo lugar, hay contradicciones, pues dices que quieres desordenar los datos pero luego dices que quieres ordenar los días, explica mejor lo que quieres!

Comment: El dataset es muy amplio ,de ese dataset uso pivot table,y selecciono index=['Mes','Dia'],que se ve bien en la primer imagen pero al hacer la agrupacion se observa que los meses estan desordenados ya que el primer mes es 1 y el ultimo 9,eso lo verifico si llevo este dataframe a un excell,para ordenar eso cree esa lista order y lo aplique usando .loc[order] y me ordeno los meses en la segunda figura se evidencia ya que en la columna mes el primero es 1 y el ultimo 12 bueno eso mismo quiero hacer con los dias ya que si ves en la segunda figura aparece en el mes 1 el  dia 1,10,11,12,13 .

Comment: Gracias ,por contestar.

Comment: seria bueno que pongas solo unos pequeños datos (una muestra) para así poder realizar las pruebas. Muy poco se podrá hacer si solo muestras el código que hace todo.

Comment: Prueba esto: verifica cual  es el tipo de datos de "Mes" y "Dia"  `subset7["Mes"].describe()` . Si el tipo de dato no es númerico conviertelo a númerico: `subset7["Mes"].astype(numpy.int32)` tienes que importar `numpy` . Lo mismo haces para el "Dia". Sospecho que te los está ordenando como cadena.

Comment: transforme subset7['Mes'].astype(numpy.int32) y lo mismo con subset7['Dia'].astype(numpy.int32) y luego hago de vuelta pivot_table de vuelta con index=['Dia','Mes'],todo lo mismo y me devuelve lo mismo desordenado.

Comment: doy el ejemplo para que se entienda

Comment: Pero falta lo último: `subset7.sort_values(by=["Mes","Dia"],inplace=True)`. Ahora los tienes ordenados. Saca tu respuesta, porque fijo que voy a poner esta. Despues haces el pivot_table

Comment: ya elimine la respuesta, no comprendí la dinámica esta de respuesta ,contestación edición, hice `subset7.sort_values(by=["Mes","Dia"],inplace=True)` no funcionó me dio error será que la  version que tengo es nueva,arriba en la imagen esta.

Comment: Quiero comentar que funciono ordenar pero para ello se debe colocar `subset7['Mes']=subset7['Mes'].astype(int)` ,`subset7['Mes']=subset7['Mes'].astype(int)`,y luego indexo Mes y Dia `subset8=subset7.pivot_table(subset7,index=['Mes','Dia'],columns=['FormaPago'],aggfunc=np.sum)` y me lo da en forma ordenada, como comento @JuanCarlosGuibovich había que pasarlo a `int` pero no a numpy.int32.,el tema es que me marca un warning como que el `.astype` va a quedar caduco.

Comment: perdon me confundi el astype no va a quedar caduco sino la forma se selecionar,ya que `subset7['Mes']=subset7['Mes'].astype(int)` es caduco la forma correcta es `subset7.loc[:, 'Mes']=subset7.loc[:,'Mes'].astype(int)`,el astype no queda caduco.

Comment: Ok, que bien que lo resolviste. Ponlo como respuesta para que no quede al aire.

Answer (score 0):

El subconjunto se lo transforma a `.astype(int)` y no a `numpy32int.` y luego se elige los index que son 'Mes' y 'Dia' y se observa los indices ordenados.

```
subset7=df[['Mes','Dia','FormaPago','CatidadPasos']]

subset7.loc[:,'Mes']=subset7.loc[:,'Dia'].astype(int)

subset7.loc[:,'Mes']=subset7.loc[:,'Mes'].astype(int)

subset7.loc[:,'CantidadPasos']=subset7.loc[:,'CantidadPasos'].astype(int)

subset8.loc[:,'CantidadPasos']=subset7.pivot_table(subset7,index=['Dia','Mes'],columns=['FormaPago'].aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? Creo que deberías editar tu pregunta añadiendo los detalles :)